# How to do Horizontal Scroll Slide Animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter-animation

[image: I want to this type scroll animation i know this is only image but that work i will explain that.]

I see that above I uploaded image is that a YouTube video thumbnail but this video does not show that thumbnail-type scroll animation I want that type of animation and that is like when I slide horizontally at that time all container slide but the center container size is decreased to side container and the center container is bigger than other two containers. I hope my question is understood so please give me a solution if anybody understands.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.